# Type int is not a subtype of type String

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

So, my app worked perfectly until I called an image using Image.asset(widget.product_detail_picture).
Here's the error:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY 
╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
 The following assertion was thrown building ProductDetails(dirty, state:
ProductDetailsState#db131):
type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'
Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should 
provide substantially more information in this error message to help you 
determine and fix the underlying cause.
```

Here's my product details page code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
```

```
  final product_detail_name;
  final product_detail_picture;
  final product_detail_old_price;
  final product_detail_new_price;

  ProductDetails({
    this.product_detail_name,
    this.product_detail_picture,
    this.product_detail_old_price,
    this.product_detail_new_price,
  });

  @override
  _ProductDetailsState createState() => _ProductDetailsState();
}

class _ProductDetailsState extends State<ProductDetails> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        title: Text('HunkyBees'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          new IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.search,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              onPressed: () {}),
          new IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.shopping_cart,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              onPressed: () {})
        ],
      ),
      body: new ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
            height: 300.0,
            child: GridTile(
                child: Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Image.asset(widget.product_detail_picture),
            )),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here's my product page where am calling the product image from

```
import '../pages/product_details.dart';

class Products extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProductsState createState() => _ProductsState();
}

class _ProductsState extends State<Products> {
  var product_list = [
    {
      "name": "Men Real Dress",
      "picture": "images/products/blazer1.jpeg",
      "old_price": 120,
      "price": 85,
    },
    {
      "name": "Red Dress",
      "picture": "images/products/dress1.jpeg",
      "old_price": 190,
      "price": 80,
    },
    {
      "name": "Women Dress",
      "picture": "images/products/dress2.jpeg",
      "old_price": 100,
      "price": 59,
    },
    {
      "name": "Women Hills",
      "picture": "images/products/hills1.jpeg",
      "old_price": 140,
      "price": 90,
    },
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
        itemCount: product_list.length,
        gridDelegate:
            new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Single_prod(
            prod_name: product_list[index]['name'],
            prod_picture: product_list[index]['picture'],
            prod_old_price: product_list[index]['old_price'],
            prod_price: product_list[index]['price'],
          );
        });
  }
}

class Single_prod extends StatelessWidget {
  final prod_name;
  final prod_picture;
  final prod_old_price;
  final prod_price;

  Single_prod(
      {this.prod_name,
      this.prod_picture,
      this.prod_old_price,
      this.prod_price});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: Hero(
        tag: prod_name,
        child: Material(
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
              new MaterialPageRoute(
                //Passing Product Details Inside Navigation Co
                builder: (context) => new ProductDetails(
                  product_detail_name: prod_name,
                  product_detail_picture: prod_old_price,
                  product_detail_new_price: prod_price,
                  product_detail_old_price: prod_old_price,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            child: GridTile(
                footer: Container(
                  color: Colors.white70,
                  child: ListTile(
                    leading: Text(
                      prod_name,
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    title: Text(
                      "\$$prod_price",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.red, fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text(
                      "\$$prod_old_price",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black54,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                          decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Image.asset(
                  prod_picture,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                )),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It worked fine without adding:
`child: Image.asset(widget.product_detail_picture),` to the product_details page

It working fine without me calling the image.

Comment: Could you please add the code where you are calling ProductDetails

Comment: I have added the product page code the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Single_prod` class, your argument to `product_detail_picture` is `int` or `double` by guessing your parsing arg varaible name(`prod_old_price`):

```
ProductDetails(
  product_detail_name: prod_name,
  product_detail_picture: prod_old_price, // this prod_old_price is not String
```

Its a good idea to take use of static type, instead of using dynamic type. One great benefit of the language you are missing and you are facing this issue, and that issue is **you are not getting compile time error when you passing an `int` to `String` variable**.

Comment: So, what do I do now?

Comment: I've been looking at my system for two days now, looking at what could be the problem. I passed prod_price to product_detail_picture. I solved it by passing the correct variable pro_picture to it. Thanks @Blasanka

Comment: @isoftTech Great to here about it! If this answer solves your problem, you can always make it correct answer. So that others will see this is as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

try to give a type like final String product_detail_picture, and make sure that `product_detail_picture` is a `String` not `int`.

```
final String product_detail_picture;
```

Image.asset must have String parameter like,

```
 Image.asset('assets/images/cake.jpg'),
```

Comment: Yes, I did it that from my product page where am calling the image from. Am calling it as object arrays.   {
      "name": "Women Dress",
      "picture": "images/products/dress2.jpeg",
      "old_price": 100,
      "price": 59,
    },

Comment: as I said in my answer you need to declare product_detail_picture as String this should not be dynamic